# Mutagen using forward slash as delimiter

Tags: python, mutagen

I'm using mutagen to collect information about given MP3 files. It's working but there is one problem. When a song has mutliple artists it uses a forward slash as a delimiter. So the TPE1 tag may return the following when the song is, e.g., a collaboration between AC/DC and Ministry:

```
['Ministry/AC/DC']
```

This is problematic when trying to isolate separate artists from the tag. Splitting on `/` won't work because this will give three results: Ministry, AC and DC. This is my code:

```
import re
import mutagen

class MusicData:
    def __init__(self, root, filepath):
        self.fullpath = root + '\\' + filepath
        
        self.prepath = re.sub(r'\\[^\\]*$', '', self.fullpath) + '\\'
        self.filename = self.fullpath.replace(self.prepath, '')

        file = mutagen.File(self.fullpath)
        self.duration = file.info.length
        
        self.title = self.extractKey(file, 'TIT2')[0]
        self.artist = self.extractKey(file, 'TPE1')[0]
        self.album = self.extractKey(file, 'TALB')[0]
        self.year = self.extractKey(file, 'TDRC')[0]
        self.genre = self.extractKey(file, 'TCON')[0]
        self.publisher = self.extractKey(file, 'TPUB')[0]
        self.key = self.extractKey(file, 'TKEY')[0]
        self.bpm = self.extractKey(file, 'TBPM')[0]
    
    def extractKey(self, file, key):
        if(key in file):
            if(type(file.tags[key].text[0]) == mutagen.id3._specs.ID3TimeStamp):
                return [str(file.tags[key].text[0])]
            else:
                return file.tags[key].text
        else:
            return [""]
```

The documentation on mutagen is very brief and is making me none the wiser. How do I properly collect the artists from a given file using mutagen?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from difference between versions of ID3 tag standard.

`v2.3.0` [defined](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116034553/http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#TPE1) `TPE1` tag as:

> The 'Lead artist(s)/Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)/Performing group' is used for the main artist(s). They are separated with the "/" character.

[`v2.4.0`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130114052304/http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) states that:

> All text information frames supports multiple strings, stored as a null
> separated list, where null is represented by the termination code
> for the character encoding. All text frame identifiers begin with "T".

Mutagen works with both versions of frames, but seems that for `v2.3.0` there is no way to specify the separator upon a file opening. So the value read is always one, regardless of presence of forward slashes inside.

I would propose converting frames to `v2.4.0` with small text processing:

```py
from typing import List


SLASH = '/'


def split_with_respect(source: str) -> List[str]:
    """
    Split the source string into artists with respect to AC/DC
    """

    result = []

    def append(word: str) -> None:
        if result and result[-1] == 'AC' and word == 'DC':
            result[-1] = 'AC/DC'
        else:
            result.append(word)

    start = 0
    while True:
        index = source.find(SLASH, start)
        if index == -1:
            append(source[start:])
            break

        append(source[start:index])
        start = index + 1

    return result
```

And the following changes the file:

```py
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TPE1, Encoding


def convert(file_name: str) -> None:

    file = ID3(file_name)

    main_artist_values = file.get('TPE1').text

    if len(main_artist_values) != 1:
        # Have a correct delimiter and already multiple values
        return

    source = main_artist_values[0]
    artists = split_with_respect(source)

    if len(artists) == 1:
        # No changes
        return

    # Rewrite the tag
    file.add(TPE1(encoding=Encoding.UTF8, text=artists))
    file.save()
```

So that reading the tag produces multiple values:

```py
>>> file = ID3(file_name)
>>> print(file.get('TPE1').text)
['Thunderstruck', 'AC/DC']
```

Python 3.11.1, Mutagen 1.47.0.